# WordPress Menus "Manage Locations" tab is missing

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a fresh install of WordPress 4.0.1 running Twenty Fourteen theme with no plugins activated.

When I go to Appearance > Menus, I only see one tab "Edit Menus". "Manage Locations" tab that I used to have in earlier versions is missing.

When I create a new menu, it's not visible. However, if I try to create a new menu with the same name, I get an error message, "The menu name TESTMENU conflicts with another menu name. Please try another."

Comment: Did you find any solution on this issue? I have the same issue here. And was wondering if there is anything I am missing. Or is this feature removed from version 4+?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out some themes does not have menu locations and you need to add theme manually through your theme's `functions.php`. Anyhow, here's what I did:

```
add_theme_support( 'menus' ); // <-- if you already see `menus` from your settings menu, you can ignore this line.

function register_menus() {

  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'primary-menu' => _( 'Primary Menu' ) // add locations here.
      'your-preferred-menu-location-id' => _( 'Title of your menu location' )
    )
  );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_menus' ); // <-- of course without this, the function above will not execute.
```

If the code above does not work for you, try enable/disable plugins that might be causing the issue.

Hope this helps.